# How to select the number of text area based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

Depending on the type of option selected, I want 1 or 3 text areas to show, i.e.,
I want 3 textareas to show up if option "mc" is selected.
I am trying to do this in Javascript, but the 3 text areas are showing up for every option selected. I think the JS function is not working. Could you please let me know where is the error.

Thanks.

Code:

```
<head>           
    <link href="./css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>          
    <h:form>                
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
              function selectans(qtype)  {                         
                if (qtype == "mc")
                {
                    alert("In MC type");
                    document.getElementById("formId:editor3").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("formId:editor4").style.display = "block";
                    //document.form.editor3.disabled = false;
                    //document.form.editor4.disabled = false;                            
                } 
                else {

                    document.getElementById("formId:editor3").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("formId:editor4").style.display = "none";
                    //document.form.editor3.disabled = true;
                    //document.form.editor4.disabled = true;
                }
              }                                                              
      </script>

       Question Type: 
       <h:selectOneMenu  id="qtype" value ="#{quizBean.qtype}" onchange="selectans(qtype) ">
           <f:selectItem id="desc" itemLabel="Descriptive Type" itemValue="desc" />
           <f:selectItem id="fill" itemLabel="Fill up the Blanks" itemValue="fill" />
           <f:selectItem id="mc" itemLabel="Multiple Choice" itemValue="mc"  />
           <f:selectItem id="tf" itemLabel="True/False" itemValue="tf" />
       </h:selectOneMenu>

       Question:                              <h:inputTextarea id="editor1" value="#{quizBean.question}" rows="20" cols="75" /> <br></br> 

       Answer:
           <h:inputText id ="editor2" value="#{quizBean.answerChoice2}"  />
           <h:inputText id ="editor3" value="#{quizBean.answerChoice2}"  />
           <h:inputText id ="editor4" value="#{quizBean.answerChoice3}"  />                                                         

            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{quizBean.addQuestion}" />
</h:form>        

</body>
```

CSS:

```css
root { 
    display: block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: add Display:None property , Show only first textarea box on load , then on click call other textarea based on click

Comment: I have added display:none property in CSS and have linked the css in the head of html

Answer (score 1):

your event function should be like this `onchange="selectans('qtype') "` In this way only a string is passed as the argument

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Made the change as suggested. Its entering the JS function, but selecting the other 2 text area is not happening.

Comment: I am not familiar with jsf. Can you test with these document.getElementById("editor3").style.display                    document.getElementById("editor4").style.display

Comment: Nope, that didnt wrk either :(

Comment: it should be working. whether your function selectans is getting called during value change.

Comment: It is entering the function. Its just not hiding the text area when needed.

Comment: After entering function is it display=none not working. is it entering the else block. Did you modified the document.getElementById("editor3").style.display in both blocks